# Concatenate JS variable to PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have a Javascript variable as "name" I want to add that to my php code. The php code uses the JS variable for a select statement. This is what I am Trying, but I am getting a syntax error;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillform(name){

        <?php $name = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = ". ?> name <?php ." "; ?>
            console.log(<?php echo $name; ?>);
        }   
</script>
```

Comment: php is a server-side language. js is a client-side language. you cannot combine it like this. You can send the variable via ajax to your server-side php code.

Comment: **Danger**: Concatenating user input into SQL makes you **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make easy to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: And your PHP syntax is not good. It's more like `<?php $name = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = "; ?> name <?php " "; ?>`

Comment: @Quentin Well, no, because what he's doing doesn't work... ;)

Comment: @FabSa: It doesn't matter. It won't work even if the statement is syntactically correct. See Quentin's comment above.

Comment: @AmalMurali It's not the solution of course but for his information :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is executed by the server.
Then the server sends the output of that code to the client in html form..
Javascript is executed by the client so you cannot combine them.

A solution could be the use of AJAX which allows javascript to call a php file and get the output of the executed code..